# How can I compare and match the `incomingArray` multidimensional array `task items and orders` are matching with the referenceArray

Tags: javascript

How can I compare and match the `incomingArray` multidimensional array `task items and orders` are matching with the referenceArray task and order items ? I have tried the below code, but it is not working though ! Is there any easy multi dimensional array matching available in js ?

```
var incomingArray = [
  { "task1": "Task A", "order": "1" },
  { "task2": "Task D", "order": "2" },
  { "task3": "Task C", "order": "3" },
  { "task4": "Task B", "order": "4" }
];

var referenceArray = [
  { "task1": "Task A", "order": "1" },
  { "task2": "Task B", "order": "2" },
  { "task3": "Task C", "order": "3" },
  { "task4": "Task D", "order": "4" }
];


function array_compare(incomingArray, referenceArray) {
 if(incomingArray.length != referenceArray.length) {
  return false;
 }
 for(var i in incomingArray) {
  if(incomingArray[i] instanceof Array && referenceArray[i] instanceof Array) {
   if(!array_compare(incomingArray[i], referenceArray[i])) {
    return false;
   }
  }
  else if(incomingArray[i] != referenceArray[i]) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no multidimensional array. It is an array of objects with n fields. And as you presuppose that they are in the same order and length it's easy to compare them.

```
function arraysAreEqual(arrayA, arrayB) {
    for (let index = 0; index < arrayA.length; index++) {
        if (arrayA[index].order !== arrayB[index].order ||
            arrayA[index]['task' + (index + 1)] !== arrayB[index]['task' + (index + 1)]){
             console.log('the arrays are unequal at index: ', index);
             console.log('ArrayA: ', arrayA[index]);
             console.log('ArrayB: ', arrayB[index]);

             return false;
        }
    }

    console.log('the arrays are equal.');

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error >> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'"`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I had a coding error in my example. The dot between the brackets was wrong.  I corrected the code right now. Please, try again.

Comment: Where can we console.log the true or false status.  If both arrays are log true else false

Comment: Hi, I edited the code. This is just a proposal. feel free to make it fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to compare them and match exactly, you can use `.forEach` and iterate over the two arrays comparing each object in a `for` loop and assign an output variable.

```js
var incomingArray = [
  {task1: "Task A",order: "1"},
  {task2: "Task D",order: "2"},
  {task3: "Task C",order: "3"},
  {task4: "Task B",order: "4"}
];

var referenceArray = [
  {task1: "Task A",order: "1"},
  {task2: "Task B",order: "2"},
  {task3: "Task C",order: "3"},
  {task4: "Task D",order: "4"}
];

var difIncomingArray = [
  {task1: "Task A",order: "1"},
  {task2: "Task B",order: "2"},
  {task3: "Task C",order: "3"},
  {task4: "Task D",order: "4"}
];

var difReferenceArray = [
  {task1: "Task A",order: "1"},
  {task2: "Task B",order: "2"},
  {task3: "Task C",order: "3"},
  {task4: "Task D",order: "4"}
];

function arrayCompare(a, b) {
  let output = false
  a.forEach((x, i) => {
      for (let j in x) {
        x[j] === b[i][j]?
          output = true :
          output = false
          return
      }
  })
  return output;
}

console.log(arrayCompare(incomingArray, referenceArray))
console.log(arrayCompare(difIncomingArray, difReferenceArray))
```